# Troubleshooting: Startup/Ignition

Tags: starting, troubleshooting, ignition, repair, service

What factors influence ignition, during startup?

Relatively modern vehicle; little over 10 years old. Owned since new. No history of related problems. Recently began to display intermittent failure to start, on a regular basis. It just cranks, turns over, then dies. Always manages to start, eventually. Sometimes it takes several turns of the key. Other times it starts on the first go. No other noticeable decline in performance.

Comment: You will get better answers if you give the make and model of the car.

Comment: Other than giving us vehicle details, it would be helpful to know what the service schedule has been. Has all servicing been done? When was the last time it had a tune-up?

Comment: It's a *VZ SS* with a *5.7 Chev LS1.* I don't expect anyone to make an accurate diagnosis, specific to me & my vehicle, online. That's why I've included my question on line #1. With that information I can ensure nothing goes overlooked. When I fix it, I'll let you all know what the problem was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the keyfob. I pulled it apart and scoured it with a small, rotary, steel brush.

I figured it out when the keyfob battery died, because its supposed to gain a charge whilst in the ignition, but it wasn't maintaining a decent contact, internally.

The immobilizer transponder is part of the same circuit. So that explains the perculiar, seemingly causeless nature of the problem.